# Connection could not be established with: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: smtp, laravel-8, smtpclient, php-7.1, php-7.3

> Connection could not be established with host
> p3plvcpnl452615.prod.phx3.secureserver.net :stream_socket_client():
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
> known

I have compared my .env and mail.php configuration file with other recent posts here for solutions. Mine looks fine, but I have yet to learn the problem.

Can someone provide me additional detail about my issue, especially the last part, php_network_getaddress? What caused it? The latest update by Go Daddy?

One more thing, I want to fix this laravel config cache with Go Daddy Terminal. Is this possible? [image: Larvel config cache]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my issue was associated with the MX record on DNS as my coworker installed the email security tool. This is the highest priority, which can stop sending an email out.
If anyone had the similar issue, check the MX on your DNS with the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are not connected to the internet

Comment: While I was testing this form, I was online.